# Word And Excel File Managment in the Network

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, file-management

I want to manage documents with Word and Excel in the network. What software and way can I use?
Please help me.

Comment: Define manage. What exactly do you want to do with these files? What are some examples of the functionality you are looking for?

Comment: Save Document on a Computer in Network And Save Who People Change Files.

Comment: Please fix your capitalization. Each question you've posted has almost all words with initial capitals. I have edited your question above to show you what it should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/), which gives you the opportunity to share folders between different users and different clients (Windows, Mac, Linux) totally integrated in the file system. It has a revision history, so you will be able to see who created/added/deleted what file. You have 2.0 Gigs of free space to use.